# Writing JSONArray to file, only writes first collection of values

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, arraylist

When the following code is executed, print function prints all the elements within the jsonarray, but the writer, only the first collection of elements.

So far I've tried what is shown in the code, plus, iterating through the list

```
public class FileWrapper {

    public static void WriteRelease(String filename, ArrayList<Object> list) throws IOException, JSONException{

        File file = new File(filename);
        FileWriter filew = new FileWriter(filename);  
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();

        //System.out.println(jsonarray.put(list).toString());
        jsonarray.add(list);
        System.out.println(jsonarray);
        jsonarray.writeJSONString(jsonarray,filew);
        filew.close();
    }
}
```

The output I want written in the file is the same as the standard output:

> [[Title - Eminem Is Back  Status - Bootleg  Language - eng 
>   ReleaseDate - 2004-09-28  Format - CD  Track Count - 11]] [[Title -
>   The Eminem Show  Status - Official  Language - eng  ReleaseDate - 2002
>   Format - Digital Media  Track Count - 20]] [[Title - The Eminem Show 
>   Status - Official  Language - eng  ReleaseDate - 2002  Format -
>   Digital Media  Track Count - 19]]

Again, what is written is only this:

> [[Title - Eminem Is Back  Status - Bootleg  Language - eng 
>   ReleaseDate - 2004-09-28  Format - CD  Track Count - 11]]

Comment: Show us the print method and how does you are calling both methods. Try to open file in append mode `new FileWriter(filename, true);`

Comment: @SatyaTNV damn simpler than I thought

Comment: With your standard output I thought like that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the work around was simple, as noted by @SatyaTNV, the only thing that needed changing was the Filewriter line

By adding

```
new FileWriter(filename, true)
```

Everything was printed fine! Thank you based SatyaTNV!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer)) {
  pw.println(jsonArray.toString());
}
```

I am not sure about writing by `JSONArray` class

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution:
[App.java class](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/getDataFromJson/blob/master/src/main/java/gradle_app/App.java)

// JSON parser object to parse read file
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

```
try {
            URL resource = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("info.json");
            System.out.println(resource.toString());
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(resource.getFile());

            // Read JSON file
            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONArray infoList = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(infoList);

            Information i = new Information();

            List<Information> info = i.parseInformationObject(infoList);

            saveInformation(info);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and iterate:
[Information.java class](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/getDataFromJson/blob/master/src/main/java/gradle_app/Information.java)

```
List<Information> parseInformationObject(JSONArray infoList) {
        List<Information> in = new ArrayList<>();

        infoList.forEach(emp -> {

            JSONObject info = (JSONObject) emp;

            String id = info.get("id").toString();
            String state = info.get("state").toString();
            String type = null;
            if (info.get("type") != null) {
                type = info.get("type").toString();
            }
            String host = null;
            if (info.get("host") != null) {
                host = info.get("host").toString();
            }
            long timestamp = (long) info.get("timestamp");

            in.add(new Information(id, state, type, host, timestamp));

        });
        return in;
    }
```